# How do I change the ASP.NET MVC default login page to login by username instead of email address?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'll go over my investigation and hopefully you guys can figure out an idea for what I should do next.

The relevant M, V and C for the login look like

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

        }
```

and

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is simply have the login be by username rather than email address. While  I can't find anything in the MVC template source code pertaining to username, I looked in the `AspNetUsers` table from the template and see that there is indeed a column called `UserName`. The trick is try and change the above source code to do what I want without causing any side effects elsewhere in the MVC template.

I changed the M to

```
public class LoginViewModel
{

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

and the V to

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" style="padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;" />
                </div>
            </div>

        }
```

The changing of the C stuff is what I'm stuck on. I know that I could do something like changing

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

to

```
var email = pingDatabaseAndGetEmailFromUsername(model.UserName);
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

But, there has to be a better way, right?

Also, it's possible that I screwed up other stuff by modifying `LoginViewModel` because other bits of code in the MVC template might use it and expect it to have an `Email` field.

So what should I actually be doing here? I want simplest change.

If I do have to change `PasswordSignInAsync`, where is the implementation? I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default template implementation uses the email address as the username, which is why it's sending the `model.Email` value to the `PasswordSignInAsync` function.  Assuming you created the user accounts with separate `Email` and `UserName` values, it should be as simple as changing the sign in method to:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

Again, this assumes your user accounts were created with distinct `UserName` and `Email` values.

Comment: Where is the implementation or documentation for PasswordSignInAsync?